# Switch between two serial ports

Tags: arduino, analog, schematics, uart, communication

I'm working on a device that is connected to 2 serial ports (both TX and RX).The first serial port is connected to a CP2104 USB chip, the second serial port is left open with TX,RX,GND,3V pins.

I want to be able to switch between these 2 ports with some kind of analog switch/multiplexer and a [mechanical switch](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Toggle-Switches_Korean-Hroparts-Elec-K3-1296S-E2_C136659.html)  but I cannot find a way to implement it.
To summarize, the user would select between USB serial or header pin serial. Pseudo-schematic:

[image: This is the circuit i want to implement]

The MCU is an ESP8266, which has only one serial port. Whenever I send data via its serial header pins it doesnt receive anything because it is already connected to the CP2104 serial port, and I dont wat to use softwareserial since it is not reliable for WiFi applications.

I did some search and found these [analog switches](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Analog-Switches_Texas-Instruments_TS5A23157TDGSRQ1_Texas-Instruments-Texas-Instruments-TS5A23157TDGSRQ1_C130086.html) but don't know how to make a circuit with a mechanical switch so that I can change from one serial port to another. Any help or advice is appreciated

**=========== EDIT 1 ============**

I found a MUX/DEMUX [analog switch](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Shanghai-Belling-BL1532MSOP_C248370.pdf) used for switching between 2 USB(D+,D-) ports. I made a prototype circuit of what I'm trying to achieve with the mechanical slide switch. What do you think?

[image]

**=========== EDIT 2 ============**
Asked another question related to this topic:
[Is this analog switch good for UART lines?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/515790/is-this-analog-switch-good-for-uart-lines?noredirect=1#515791)

Comment: Analog switches are indeed sometimes used for this.  Or use digital muxes or buffers with enable, and respect the direction...  If you're using an actual *mechanical* switch you may not have too much difficulty finding one with two circuits which would solve the problem entirely, typically you don't need to (and should not!) break the ground.

Comment: If / When you create a schematic in CircuitLab please save it directly to the page, as we can copy and edit it to show a solution without having to create it from scratch. Or give us the URL to the schematic so we can copy it. As it is right now we have to create a schematic for you from scratch, which takes time as these are custom symbols you created.

Comment: why do you need a mux and a mechanical switch? ... it is unclear how the two relate to each other

Comment: @jsotola The mechanical slide switch would be used to select between USB and header pins since it has only two positions. I don't want to drive the UART lines via the mechanical switch because of the low resistance which may cause corrupted data. I'd rather drive the UART via a MUX or some sort of analog switch which is driven by a digital signal or vcc

Comment: @ChrisStratton Yes I also thought about using only a mechanical switch (DPDT) but I'm concerned about the low resistance connections it may cause on the UART lines (garbage data?) when switching

Comment: In the scope of a hobby project, that's unlikely to be a leading issue.  In the scope of a product design, there's probably a lot that should be considered first, such as what this other serial port is needed for in the first place...

Comment: @ChrisStratton The other serial port (header pins) is used to read serial data from other devices like Arduinos, Rpi's, GPS modules,...... In reality, it's not a big deal if I get some garbage data, I just need to make sure it will switch from USB to header pins and receive/send data through it

Comment: That's not unexpected.   But in designing a *product* where the switch concerns would be barely real concerns, you should probably first be reconsidering the entire system diagram.  For a one-off hobby project, just use a switch and move on, or get rid of the on-board USB-UART and plug in an external one via a header when you need it.

Comment: @AminMansouri, the slide switch should be drawn in the block diagram connected to the mux control pins ... the slide switch is actually irrelevant to the question because the mux is selected electronically anyway ... the select signal can come from any number of sources ... making the slide switch important in the question only adds confusion

Comment: @ChrisStratton I think a found a good [mux/demux chip](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Shanghai-Belling-BL1532MSOP_C248370.pdf) used for USB (D+,D-) line switching. I think it would be a good choice since it has OE and SEL pins to switch between lines. There's a function table on page 2

Comment: While you can probably make some mux chip work, it really seems like unnecessary complexity especially where the overall system design seems not to have yet received due attention.  If you really wanted to, I believe that with the right PC side software you could make the CP2104 tristate its pins.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I made a circuit: [image](https://imgur.com/6W1ah81)

Comment: @jsotola i made this circuit: [image](https://imgur.com/a/yaLMg5L)

Comment: Just use ressistors between the UART bridge and the serial port,  that's how arduino does it.

Answer (score 4):

just use a DPDT switch

[image]

[edit] Choosing the right kind of switch is important.

As the signal is a low voltage and low current you want a type of switch
where the contacts are self cleaning, like a rotary or slide switch.

Comment: Often there is not enough current in data lines to make switch or relay contacts behave as low resistance connections. A mux is much more dependable.

Comment: Contact bounce is not an issue if you switch when there is no transmission ongoing. Even if transmission is ongoing, it will get corrupted even without contact bounce. Back in the days when RS232 serial ports were more common, external boxes existed to select which one of multiple RS232 devices was connected to the computer. They used a mechanical switch, so this is true and tried way to switch. In some other cases, yes, it may not be a good idea to route data via mechanical switches.

Comment: yeah, choosing the right kind of switch is important.

Comment: Use the smallest switch and gnd path path possible with logic level control to switch. <1cm loop path for sig + gnd due to inductance

Comment: @Jasen I think I found the perfect chip for this: [analog mux/demux](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/Analog-Switches_BL-Shanghai-Belling-BL1532MSOP_C248370.html)

Comment: @Jasen I made this circuit based on the BL1532 analog switch: [image](https://imgur.com/a/yaLMg5L)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  I made this circuit based on the BL1532 analog switch: [image](https://imgur.com/a/yaLMg5L)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75  why so extreme? 100mm loopd should not case a problem with such a slow signal

Comment: This is high speed CMOS with USB data rates 48MHz clock

Comment: no, it's asynchronous serial (NRZ) maximum 2Megabits per second

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The datasheet says its TTL compatible so I guess it may work for UART